# How to use a groupBy filter in controller level in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys i have this json object:

```
var myData=[{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Safi","serie":"CZC1448YZN"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Safi","serie":"2UA13817KT"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Rabat","serie":"CZC1349G1B"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Rabat","serie":"  2UA0490SVR"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Agdal","serie":" G3M4NOJ"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Essaouira","serie":" CZC1221B85"},{"agence":"Gare Routiere Municipale","secteur":"Essaouira","serie":" CZC145YL3"}] ;
```

what i want is to use a group by filter in the contriller level to as this result:

```
-Safi
        -CTM
            CZC1448YZN
            2UA13817KT

-Rabat
        -CTM
            CZC1349G1B
            2UA0490SVR
        -Agdal
            G3M4NOJ
-Essaouira
        -CTM
            CZC1221B85
        -Gare Routiere Municipale
            CZC145YL3
```

is that possible..hepl please..
PS:i dont want to use group by filter in ng-repeat directive but i want use it in the controller

Comment: have you tried with Lodash? https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#groupBy

Answer (score 0):

have you tried maybe something like (with Lodash support):

```
$scope.myVarGrouped= _.groupBy(myData,'agence');
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it gives me an error.... Cannot read property 'groupBy' of undefined

Comment: you neeed to install lodash before .. import it with CDN .. or via NPM

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: it works...but its not the expected behaviour..take a look heres:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397428/how-to-use-a-groupby-with-json-file-angularjs